# Who had 3 rules for submissions: 1. You must have a point. 2. You must make your point. 3. You must make it in pristine, first-rate english?

Tags: editing, quotes

I think it was a famous magazine editor. I must be butchering the quote because Google search is absolutely no help on this one. In particular, I really don't remember how the third rule was exactly phrased.

I remember reading about a famous editor at a famous magazine that was known for edgy content. I think it probably existed in the 1980s or earlier. The editor was known for accepting submissions covering a very wide variety of topics, and they had very high standards for quality, and they had these three rules. I wanted to look them up to remind myself of exactly how they went.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Unfortunately I have to agree with the close-voters; this isn't really a question about writing. It *might* be on-topic on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), but check their [on-topic guidelines](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.